# Windows Service as "PrintServer"

Tags: c#, wcf, printing

In my application I have several `DataGrids`. I want to print the Content of the `DataGrid` with a Printer, which is located anywhere in the building. I want to use a PrintServer for it, so every user of my application can print over this PrintServer.

Is it a good idea to create a Windows Service which will handle the printing and lays on a Server or for testing on the same machine, I'm developing on?

Answer (score 0):

WCF - is a good approach to use in Service-Oriented Architecture. The term 'service' here - is web-application(API,web-interface), and is not a windows service(like daemons in linux). WCF services working on IIS server. It is simple to create a web-api for your "PrintService", I think it's not a bad idea. Sorry for my ENGLISH=)